# How can I manage other forms under the main form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to manage `form2` to `form9` under the main `form1` in my project.

`form1` contains a `menustrip` and from that I call the other forms with code

```
form3.show()
```

The problem is when I minimize `form1` the other forms still stand alone and I must minimize all forms individually

I want one main form - `form1` - that I can use to open other forms under their windows.

So `form1` minimize than all other forms also minimize.

Comment: form3.Show(this);

Comment: To add to the comment by Hans Passant, which should be `form3.Show(Me)` in VB.Net (`this` is C#, along with the semi-colon), using that overload of [Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) sets the `Owner` of the Form resulting in the desired behavior.

Comment: If by *open other forms under their windows* you mean "one form that contains other forms, like MS Word did in the old days" - you perhaps need to look at what MDI is?

Comment: Thanks     Idle_Mind, hans passant

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is work with the tabcontrol.

U put a tabcontrol on your mainForm and everytime u wanna open a new form u just add that form to a tabcontrolpage.

The code would look like this

```
Dim frm = New form1

   Dim page = New C1DockingTabPage

        page.Text = frm.Text
        frm.ws_Employee_UID.Text = ws_Employee_UID.Text
        frm.TopLevel = False
        frm.FormBorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        frm.ControlBox = False

        page.Controls.Add(frm)
        Me.C1DockingTab1.TabPages.Add(page)
        frm.Show()
        page.Show()
```

or like said u could learn MDI, but i prefer the TabControl.